# C missing and no known rule to make it

Tags: c, codeblocks, clion

I am new in C and I just installed CLion. I just created a new project and I'm trying to run "default" code from CLion.

```
int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But I got an error:

```
ninja: error: 'C:/Users/Kagan LaÃ§in/CLionProjects/untitled1/main.c',
needed by 'CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/main.c.obj', missing and no known rule
to make it
```

There's no "main.c.obj" file in that direction, it's right but why does not CLion create that? How can I solve this? I was using CodeBlocks before, I removed completely that. I did reboot 2-3 times. Still same.

Comment: I wouild not use not ascii characters in the path

Comment: CLion is not complaining that `main.c.obj` is missing.  That's indeed a file it wants to build.  But it's complaining that the corresponding source file, `main.c`, is missing.  Is it wrong? Do pay careful attention to the full path where it expects to find the file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the build system is getting confused by "ç" in your name. Unfortunately a lot of programming software is made by people who only speak English and it has problems like this. Put your project in a folder like C:\CLionProjects\untitled1 without a "ç"